# Asus ROG G752VT alsa configuration

Tags: alsa, asus, jack

So I have this issue that I tried so hard to fix but can't. On my Asus G752VT when the headphones are plugged in the sound still goes through the build-in speakers. And I know there are many fixes described....but none worked.

So...I tried adding options to the alsa-base.conf file, didn't really work. I tried to work around with the hdajackretask tool but did not work (I am sure tho that I did not do everything properly as there aren'y many guides on that).

I tried to follow this thread but I got stuck badly...

https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1093558-start-0.html

Through this process, I learned about this tool evtest. And I observed an issue, my laptop has 3 ports for sound, combo (micro + jack), jack and micro. When I test for events for Intel HDA PHC Line Out nothing happens when I plug/unplug the jack, it only reacts for the combo port...

Even tho in the pavucontrol it still shows unplugged

If somebody was able to figure out how to fix this...please can describe the process, but in detail for a newbee...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I was able to find a solution, still using the guide specified above, just simplified-ish as well as the original solution from this guy

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213137

I just created a file /lib/firmware/asus-g752vt.fw where it contained this information

```
[codec]
0x10ec0668 0x10431ced 0

[pincfg]
#Pin 12 is Internal Mic
0x12 0x90a60160
#Pin 14 is Internal "front" speakers
0x14 0x90170110
#Pin 15 is "Line Out" according to the manual, But Pin 15 won't work
#Trying to use this as an output will have a constant tone too.
#Using this as an output breaks the front speakers working correctly with deteciton
0x15 0x40f000f0
#Pin 16 is the headphone jack.
0x16 0x0321403f
#Pin 18 is the external Microphone jack.
0x18 0x03a19020
#Pin 19 is nothing.
0x19 0x411111f0
#Pin 1a is the internal subwoofer.  (Set the sound system to Stereo 2.1)
0x1a 0x90170151
#Pin 1b is nothing.
0x1b 0x411111f0
#Pin 1d is nothing.
0x1d 0x40c6852d
#Pin 1e is the internal SPDIF out.
0x1e 0x014b1180
#Pin 1f is nothing.
0x1f 0x411111f0
```

and then added a option to the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel enable=1 index=0 enable_msi=1 model=asus-mode5 patch=asus-g752vt.fw
```

reboot and works.

Comment: How do you "*set the sound system to 2.1*"?